# Is it possible to download a section of a HTML file programmatically?

Tags: html, http

Can one define a section of an HTML webpage to download (typically using HTTP), instead of the whole file, and utilize this in a program to save bandwidth? For example, in C# (but I guess the language is not important).

Comment: how could you possibly define a "section" of the file without knowing about the contents of the file? I guess if the web server was configured for it, you could make it serve requests for a "substring" of an html file, but I haven't heard of it. exactly what is it you are trying to do, and why?

Comment: You can request ranges of bytes, but you won't get a nice expressive query language.

Comment: I guess it could be done with a special server which converts the html to xhtml first, provides the web pages in form of an xml database, and provides an http based API to that xml database, allowing to execute queries in some xml query language like xpath or xquery. However, a standard web server won't support this.

Answer (score 4):

No, but most HTML files aren't that large anyway; the "heavy" parts of the content are the images.

It's not about C# or choice of language in general; the HTTP protocol doesn't define any way to make a request for a specific section of an HTML file.

Comment: … and it *cannot possibly* do so, since HTTP only transports octet streams, it doesn't even *know* anything about HTML.

Comment: although technically speaking, the question didn't mention HTTP! in theory, you could make a web server that does just this, but yeah, in the general case it's not possible.

Comment: FYI: HTTP has a way to define a section using bytes: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233 (June 2014), however this usually doesn't work when you need certain sections of a html page since the size is not fixed